# asp.net redirect a page in NEW TAB on dropdown list onselectedindexchanged by passing query string

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

This is my code. Plz help me to redirect the page in new tab.
It can be either by script or c# code.
Thanks in advance.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcomplaint" CssClass="list-item-width1" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" 
                                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcomplaint_SelectedIndexChanged" onchange="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';">



protected void ddlcomplaint_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtTitle.Text = "";
        int complaint = Convert.ToInt16(ddlcomplaint.SelectedValue);
        if (complaint == 100)
        {
            txtTitle.Enabled = true;

        }
        else
        {
            txtTitle.Enabled = true;
            txtTitle.Text = ddlcomplaint.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();

        }
        string Title = ddlcomplaint.SelectedItem.Text;

        Response.Redirect("/SearchComplaint.aspx?Title=" + Title);



    }
```

Comment: Response.Redirect("javascript:window.open(/SearchComplaint.aspx?Title=" + Title));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JavaScript**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Redirect() {
            var ddl1 = document.getElementById('<%= ddlcomplaint.ClientID %>');
            var selectedval = ddl1.options[ddl1.selectedIndex].value;
            window.open("/SearchComplaint.aspx?Title=" + selectedval );
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" onchange="Redirect();">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

or

**c#**

```
protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"OpenWindow","window.open('/SearchComplaint.aspx?Title=" + Title');",true);
    }
```

Comment: JavaScript is working. But it is redirecting in the current tab itself. I want in new tab. Help me plz

Comment: You told that javascript is working,but navigating in the same page.So i changed that javascript code..can u see that..Instead of window.location.href i added window.open.Use this it will work..

Comment: I have used window.open..but, its not working..is there any other way?

Comment: If i use window.Open its not even redirecting in same page even. i dnt know where the prob is :(